# IPMI-config cannot set SOL (serial over LAN) baudrate

Tags: ipmi

I have a MSI MS-S0121 Mainboard with an AST2150 BMC controller with IPMI 2.0.

I'm using `ipmiconsole` from freeipmi and serial-over-lan (SOL) to access the BIOS. The default baudrate of 19200 is quite slow, so i would like to set it to 115200 baud. But it seems that i can only set it to the value of 19200 it's already on:

```
[marvin@t5600 ~]$ ipmi-config -h 172.16.0.158 --username=admin --password=admin --commit -e SOL_Conf:Volatile_Bit_Rate=19200
[marvin@t5600 ~]$ ipmi-config -h 172.16.0.158 --username=admin --password=admin --commit -e SOL_Conf:Volatile_Bit_Rate=115200
ERROR: Failed to commit `SOL_Conf:Volatile_Bit_Rate'
[marvin@t5600 ~]$ ipmi-config -h 172.16.0.158 --username=admin --password=admin --checkout > bmc.conf
```

```
#
# Section UserX Comments 
#
# In the following User sections, users should configure usernames, passwords, 
# and access rights for IPMI over LAN communication. Usernames can be set to any 
# string with the exception of User1, which is a fixed to the "anonymous" 
# username in IPMI. 
#
# For IPMI over LAN access for a username, set "Enable_User" to "Yes", 
# "Lan_Enable_IPMI_Msgs" to "Yes", and "Lan_Privilege_Limit" to a privilege 
# level. The privilege level is used to limit various IPMI operations for 
# individual usernames. It is recommended that atleast one username be created 
# with a privilege limit "Administrator", so all system functions are available 
# to atleast one username via IPMI over LAN. For security reasons, we recommend 
# not enabling the "anonymous" User1. For most users, "Lan_Session_Limit" can be 
# set to 0 (or ignored) to support an unlimited number of simultaneous IPMI over 
# LAN sessions. 
#
# If your system supports IPMI 2.0 and Serial-over-LAN (SOL), 
# a"SOL_Payload_Access" field may be listed below. Set the "SOL_Payload_Access" 
# field to "Yes" or "No" to enable or disable this username's ability to access 
# SOL. 
#
# Please do not forget to uncomment those fields, such as "Password", that may 
# be commented out during the checkout. 
#
# Some motherboards may require a "Username" to be configured prior to other 
# fields being read/written. If this is the case, those fields will be set to 
# <username-not-set-yet>. 
#
Section User1
    ## Give Username
    ## Username                                   NULL
    ## Give password or blank to clear. MAX 16 chars (20 chars if IPMI 2.0 supported).
    ## Password                                   
    ## Possible values: Yes/No or blank to not set
    ## Enable_User                                
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_IPMI_Msgs                          Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_Link_Auth                          Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_Restricted_to_Callback             No
    ## Possible values: Callback/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary/No_Access
    Lan_Privilege_Limit                           Administrator
    ## Possible values: 0-17, 0 is unlimited; May be reset to 0 if not specified
    ## Lan_Session_Limit                          
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    SOL_Payload_Access                            Yes
EndSection
Section User2
    ## Give Username
    Username                                      Operator
    ## Give password or blank to clear. MAX 16 chars (20 chars if IPMI 2.0 supported).
    ## Password                                   
    ## Possible values: Yes/No or blank to not set
    ## Enable_User                                
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_IPMI_Msgs                          Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_Link_Auth                          Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_Restricted_to_Callback             No
    ## Possible values: Callback/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary/No_Access
    Lan_Privilege_Limit                           Operator
    ## Possible values: 0-17, 0 is unlimited; May be reset to 0 if not specified
    ## Lan_Session_Limit                          
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    SOL_Payload_Access                            Yes
EndSection
Section User3
    ## Give Username
    Username                                      admin
    ## Give password or blank to clear. MAX 16 chars (20 chars if IPMI 2.0 supported).
    ## Password                                   
    ## Possible values: Yes/No or blank to not set
    ## Enable_User                                
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_IPMI_Msgs                          Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_Link_Auth                          Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_Restricted_to_Callback             No
    ## Possible values: Callback/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary/No_Access
    Lan_Privilege_Limit                           Administrator
    ## Possible values: 0-17, 0 is unlimited; May be reset to 0 if not specified
    ## Lan_Session_Limit                          
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    SOL_Payload_Access                            Yes
EndSection
Section User4
    ## Give Username
    Username                                      OEM
    ## Give password or blank to clear. MAX 16 chars (20 chars if IPMI 2.0 supported).
    ## Password                                   
    ## Possible values: Yes/No or blank to not set
    ## Enable_User                                
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_IPMI_Msgs                          Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_Link_Auth                          Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Lan_Enable_Restricted_to_Callback             No
    ## Possible values: Callback/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary/No_Access
    Lan_Privilege_Limit                           OEM_Proprietary
    ## Possible values: 0-17, 0 is unlimited; May be reset to 0 if not specified
    ## Lan_Session_Limit                          
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    SOL_Payload_Access                            Yes
EndSection
#
# Section Lan_Channel Comments 
#
# In the Lan_Channel section, general IPMI over LAN can be enabled for disabled. 
# In the below, "Volatile" configurations are immediately configured onto the 
# BMC and will have immediate effect on the system. "Non_Volatile" 
# configurations are only available after the next system reset. Generally, both 
# the "Volatile" and "Non_Volatile" equivalent fields should be configured 
# identically. 
#
# To enable IPMI over LAN, typically "Access_Mode" should be set to 
# "Always_Available". "Channel_Privilege_Limit" should be set to the highest 
# privilege level any username was configured with. Typically, this is set to 
# "Administrator". 
#
# "User_Level_Auth" and "Per_Message_Auth" are typically set to "Yes" for 
# additional security. 
#
Section Lan_Channel
    ## Possible values: Disabled/Pre_Boot_Only/Always_Available/Shared
    Volatile_Access_Mode                          Always_Available
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Volatile_Enable_User_Level_Auth               Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Volatile_Enable_Per_Message_Auth              Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Volatile_Enable_Pef_Alerting                  Yes
    ## Possible values: Callback/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary
    Volatile_Channel_Privilege_Limit              OEM_Proprietary
    ## Possible values: Disabled/Pre_Boot_Only/Always_Available/Shared
    Non_Volatile_Access_Mode                      Always_Available
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Non_Volatile_Enable_User_Level_Auth           Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Non_Volatile_Enable_Per_Message_Auth          Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Non_Volatile_Enable_Pef_Alerting              Yes
    ## Possible values: Callback/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary
    Non_Volatile_Channel_Privilege_Limit          OEM_Proprietary
EndSection
#
# Section Lan_Conf Comments 
#
# In the Lan_Conf section, typical networking configuration is setup. Most users 
# will choose to set "Static" for the "IP_Address_Source" and set the 
# appropriate "IP_Address", "MAC_Address", "Subnet_Mask", etc. for the machine. 
#
Section Lan_Conf
    ## Possible values: Unspecified/Static/Use_DHCP/Use_BIOS/Use_Others
    IP_Address_Source                             Static
    ## Give valid IP address
    IP_Address                                    172.16.0.158
    ## Give valid MAC address
    MAC_Address                                   AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
    ## Give valid Subnet Mask
    Subnet_Mask                                   255.255.0.0
    ## Give valid IP address
    Default_Gateway_IP_Address                    0.0.0.0
    ## Give valid MAC address
    Default_Gateway_MAC_Address                   00:00:00:00:00:00
EndSection
#
# Section Lan_Conf_Auth Comments 
#
# In the Lan_Conf_Auth section, allowable authentication mechanisms for IPMI 1.5 
# is configured. Most users will want to set all "MD5" authentication to "Yes" 
# and the rest to "No". If you have configured a NULL username and a NULL 
# password, you will also want to configure some of the "None" fields to "Yes" 
# to allow "None" authentication to work. Some motherboards do not allow you to 
# enable OEM authentication, so you may wish to set all OEM related fields to 
# "No". 
#
Section Lan_Conf_Auth
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Callback_Enable_Auth_Type_None                Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Callback_Enable_Auth_Type_MD5                 Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Callback_Enable_Auth_Type_Straight_Password   Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    User_Enable_Auth_Type_None                    Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    User_Enable_Auth_Type_MD5                     Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    User_Enable_Auth_Type_Straight_Password       Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Operator_Enable_Auth_Type_None                Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Operator_Enable_Auth_Type_MD5                 Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Operator_Enable_Auth_Type_Straight_Password   Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Admin_Enable_Auth_Type_None                   Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Admin_Enable_Auth_Type_MD5                    Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Admin_Enable_Auth_Type_Straight_Password      Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    OEM_Enable_Auth_Type_None                     Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    OEM_Enable_Auth_Type_MD5                      Yes
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    OEM_Enable_Auth_Type_Straight_Password        Yes
EndSection
#
# Section Lan_Conf_Security_Keys Comments 
#
# If your system supports IPMI 2.0 and Serial-over-LAN (SOL), a K_g BMC key may 
# be configurable. The K_g key is an optional key that can be set for two key 
# authentication in IPMI 2.0. It is optionally configured. Most users will want 
# to set this to zero (or blank). 
#
Section Lan_Conf_Security_Keys
    ## Give string or blank to clear. Max 20 bytes, prefix with 0x to enter hex
    K_G                                           0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
EndSection
#
# Section Lan_Conf_User_Security Comments 
#
# The following user security configuration options are optionally implemented 
# by the vendor. They may not be available your system and may not be visible 
# below. 
#
# The following configuration supports the ability for the BMC to disable a user 
# if a number of bad passwords are entered sequentially. 
# "Bad_Password_Threshold" determines the number of bad passwords that must be 
# entered sequentially. "Attempt_Count_Reset_Interval" determines the range of 
# time the bad passwords must occur in. "User_Lockout_Interval" determines the 
# time a user will be locked off if the bad password threshold is reached. If 
# set to "Yes", "Enable_Event_Message_When_User_Disabled" will inform the BMC to 
# log an event message when a user is disabled. 
#
Section Lan_Conf_User_Security
EndSection
#
# Section Lan_Conf_Misc Comments 
#
# The following miscellaneous configuration options are optionally implemented 
# by the vendor. They may not be available your system and may not be visible 
# below. 
#
# If set to "Yes", "Enable_Gratuitous_ARPs" will inform the BMC to regularly 
# send out Gratuitous ARPs to allow other machines on a network resolve the 
# BMC's MAC Address. Many users will want to set this to "Yes" because it offers 
# the easiest way to support BMC IP Address resolution. However, it will 
# increase traffic on your network. The "Gratuitous_ARP_Interval" can be used to 
# set the period a Gratuitous ARP is always sent. 
#
# If set to "Yes", "Enable_ARP_Response" will inform the BMC torespond to ARP 
# requests from other machines. 
#
Section Lan_Conf_Misc
EndSection
#
# Section Rmcpplus_Conf_Privilege Comments 
#
# If your system supports IPMI 2.0 and Serial-over-LAN (SOL),cipher suite IDs 
# may be configurable below. In the Rmcpplus_Conf_Privilege section, maximum 
# user privilege levels allowed for authentication under IPMI 2.0 (including 
# Serial-over-LAN) are set for each supported cipher suite ID. Each cipher suite 
# ID supports different sets of authentication, integrity, and encryption 
# algorithms for IPMI 2.0. Typically, the highest privilege level any username 
# configured should set for support under a cipher suite ID. This is typically 
# "Administrator". 
#
Section Rmcpplus_Conf_Privilege
    ## Possible values: Unused/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary
    Maximum_Privilege_Cipher_Suite_Id_0           OEM_Proprietary
    ## Possible values: Unused/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary
    Maximum_Privilege_Cipher_Suite_Id_1           OEM_Proprietary
    ## Possible values: Unused/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary
    Maximum_Privilege_Cipher_Suite_Id_2           OEM_Proprietary
    ## Possible values: Unused/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary
    Maximum_Privilege_Cipher_Suite_Id_3           OEM_Proprietary
EndSection
#
# Section SOL_Conf Comments 
#
# If your system supports IPMI 2.0 and Serial-over-LAN (SOL), the following 
# configuration options will allow SOL configuration. 
#
# For most users that want to enable SOL, minimally "Enable_SOL" should be set 
# to "Yes" and "SOL_Privilege_Level" should be set to the highest privilege 
# level any username configured can authenticate with (typically 
# "Administrator"). For security purposes, "Force_SOL_Payload_Authentication" 
# and "Force_SOL_Payload_Encryption" should be set to "Yes", however forced 
# authentication and/or encryption depends on the cipher suite IDs supported. 
# The "Non_Volatile_Bit_Rate" and "Volatile_Bit_Rate" should both be set to the 
# appropriate baud rate for your system. This is typically the same baud rate 
# configured in the BIOS and/or operating system. 
#
Section SOL_Conf
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Enable_SOL                                    Yes
    ## Possible values: Callback/User/Operator/Administrator/OEM_Proprietary
    SOL_Privilege_Level                           Administrator
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Force_SOL_Payload_Authentication              No
    ## Possible values: Yes/No
    Force_SOL_Payload_Encryption                  No
    ## Give a non-zero valid integer. Each unit is 5ms
    Character_Accumulate_Interval                 20
    ## Give a valid number
    Character_Send_Threshold                      80
    ## Give a valid integer
    SOL_Retry_Count                               7
    ## Give a valid integer. Interval unit is 10ms
    SOL_Retry_Interval                            250
    ## Possible values: Serial/9600/19200/38400/57600/115200
    Non_Volatile_Bit_Rate                         19200
    ## Possible values: Serial/9600/19200/38400/57600/115200
    Volatile_Bit_Rate                             19200
    ## Give a valid port number
    ## SOL_Payload_Port_Number                    623
EndSection
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @A.B yes, only 19200 works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the BMC (Baseboard Management Controller) is connected to the NIC via a slow out-of-band bus, e.g. see the diagram in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface), where it is an [SMBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus).

This means the baud rate is restricted by the characteristics of this bus. So, depending on the hardware, it will work only at specific baud rates or up to specific baud rates, and therefore sometimes (as in your case) you are prevented from setting the baud rate in IMPI SOL mode.

And even if you could modify the baud rate, as the maximum speed is determined by another bus and not the serial connection, it wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

19200 bps is by no means fast, but I've done quite a bit of Unix system management (HP-UX, to be specific) over basic GSM-Data connections. That is 9600 bps over the radio interface, and some significant latency thrown in.

It's doable, but you really don't want to do anything more than necessary, and you'll learn to estimate in advance the likely amount of output your commands will be producing. If a command unexpectedly spews more output than expected, even if you hit Control-C immediately, there will already be quite a bit of data buffered in the connection, trickling its way toward your screen, so you'll be watching the output scroll by for a while.

Besides, you can take it as a retrocomputing experience. :-)
"That's about how Ken Thompson and Dennis Ritchie (the original developers of Unix) did all their work, back in the day."

I found [this manual for the AST2150](https://docplayer.net/18147941-Ast2150-ipmi-configuration-guide.html). It includes this bit:

> Note that for IPMITool SOL session, user needs to use BIOS setup menu to configure “Remote Serial Console Redirect” to use COMA, and set baud rate to 38.4K, 8 bits, no parity, and Xon/Xoff handshaking.

This suggests that 38400 bps might be the *only* baud rate that actually works with this particular chip or system.

I have a system that includes the AST2400 chip, and its documentation likewise suggests using a specific baud rate of 57600. Before I noticed that information, I made a pretty exhaustive search on other possible values, and I can confirm that on my Asus P10S-I at least, 57600 bps seems indeed to be the only baud rate that actually works over the SOL connection.

Also, when changing the bit rate with `ipmi-config`, try changing the non-volatile bit rate first, and make sure you set both the volatile and non-volatile bit rates to the same value.